# Is it possible to nest hazelcast IMaps? And whick side effects can I expect? Is it a good Idea anyway?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am just wondering if it is possible to nest IMaps. The quick and simple way says "no".

```
    @Test
    public void nest(){
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        IMap<Object, Object> foo = instance.getMap("foo");
        IMap<Object, Object> bar = instance.getMap("bar");

        bar.lock("bar key");
        bar.set("bar key", "mmmmm");
        bar.unlock("bar key");

        foo.lock("foo key");
        foo.set("foo key", bar);
        foo.unlock("foo key");

        System.out.println(foo);
    }
```

Results in:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:215)
    at
```

But I mean at the end of the day we just need to know the nested maps name right? So I did a quick and dirty shot:

```
@Test
public void nest(){
    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IMap<Object, Object> foo = instance.getMap("foo");
    IMap<Object, Object> bar = instance.getMap("bar");

    bar.lock("bar key");
    bar.set("bar key", "mmmmm");
    bar.unlock("bar key");


    foo.lock("foo key");
    foo.set("foo key", new NestedIMap("bar"));
    foo.unlock("foo key");

    for (Object ky : foo.keySet()) {
        Object o = foo.get(ky);
        if (o instanceof NestedIMap) {
            NestedIMap bar1 = (NestedIMap) o;
            bar1.setInstance(instance);

            System.out.println("nested map");
            for (Object ky2 : bar1.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(bar1.get(ky2));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}

public static class NestedIMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>, Serializable {
    private final String name;
    private transient HazelcastInstance instance = null;
    private transient IMap cache = null;


    public NestedIMap(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setInstance(HazelcastInstance instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public IMap<K,V> getIMap() {
        return cache != null ? cache : (cache = instance.getMap(name));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return getIMap().size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return getIMap().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return getIMap().containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return getIMap().containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return getIMap().get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return getIMap().put(key,value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return getIMap().remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        getIMap().putAll(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        getIMap().clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return getIMap().keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return getIMap().values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return getIMap().entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getIMap().toString();
    }
}
```

Soo ... just because this code is running I am not sure if this is a good idea specially if I use this in a distributed cluster system. Do anyone know which side effects this will have?

Comment: Just a vague idea: Instead of nested maps that can be accessed like `map.get(keyA).get(keyB)`, you might consider a *single* map that maps from *tuples* to the respective value, and can be accessed like `map.get(tupleOf(keyA,keyB))`. Not sure if this solution is applicable (or whether it is the "best" solution) in your case, but that's the standard way of "flattening" nested maps, and could simplify things a lot (for the user, as well as for Hazelcast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible (from serialization side) but I wouldn't recommend it to be done.

Comment: yeah I think so too but sometimes I have very big values (~1GB binary data) and I thought about not only splitting keys/values over the cluster but also distribute single values. I am not sure if I can keep everything in sync with this "solution"

Comment: Maybe you can use combined keys from real key and incrementing numbers to slice the value into multiple smaller ones?